# focus children component using createRef doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this as parent

```
class TestRef extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();
  render() {
    return <Hello ref={this.ref} />;
  }
}
```

and my Hello is like so

```
export default ({ ref }) => <input ref={ref} />;
```

but I always got {value: null}

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/7wo7qvkq8j

Comment: Problem #1: **Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ref` is not a standard prop. You can change it to something else (`myRef`), or use [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html):

```
const Hello = React.forwardRef((props,  ref) => <input ref={ref} />);
```

**Node:** ref forwarding works with React 16.3 (not alpha) and above.

Demo ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pjwr0j4l00)):

```js
const Hello = React.forwardRef((props,  ref) => <input ref={ref} />);

class TestRef extends React.Component {

  ref = React.createRef();
  
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.ref);
    
    this.ref.current.focus(); // example of using the ref
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Hello ref={this.ref} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestRef />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what if your input is within a loop, do I have to create dynamic ref? https://codesandbox.io/s/v037n0jvp7

Comment: You'll need to create a ref for everyone of them.

Comment: just for 2 input's focus omg, why not just `${'.input1).focus()`

Comment: Because it's not jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change `ref` to another word due to conflict with [special props](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html). See my edited code: https://codesandbox.io/s/82m5lzy4vj

But I recommend you shouldn't pass ref via props. You can create ref at that component and control it.